# Articulate non-blocking to blocking events in pyglet

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I'm developing a game in pyglet, that scheduled by a simple text file like :

```
0:00:01;event1
0:00:02;event2
0:00:03;event3
```

The fact is that, among these events, some might be blocking (for instance `event2` might consist in displaying instructions until a key is pressed). As a consequence, `event3` might not be executed at the proper time (i.e., during the `event2`). For now, my strategy is to schedule one event after the other :

1. Execute the first event
2. Once the first event is finished, compute the remaining duration between the first and the second event (`delta_duration`)
3. Schedule the second event with a delay of `delta_duration`

... and so on

For now, I did not succeed in implementing properly a blocking event with this strategy. It seems that anything blocking the event_loop (like a `sleep` call during `event2`) is preventing even the graphical elements of `event2` (text instructions) to be displayed. On the other hand, if I do not put any blocking routine (`sleep`) in the `event2`, I'm able to see the vertices, but the scheduler keeps on scheduling (!), and so the `event3` comes too soon.

My question is : what would be a general strategy, in pyglet, to articulate non-blocking to blocking events ? More precisely, is it possible (desirable) to use multiple clocks for that purpose ? The pyglet documentation mentions that multiple clocks can be used but it is not very well explained.

I don't want a solution that is specific to my `events` example but, rather, general indications about the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to your program on what blocks.  If you are using `input` from Python for the console window, then yes that will block because it's blocking execution of Python in general. If you have a label popup in the window that is waiting for input from an `on_key_press` window event, then that is completely different as it's not blocking the pyglet loop, it was scheduled within it.

If your event is a 20 second long math calculation, then that should probably be ran in a thread. You will probably have to separate the types of events in order to differentiate how they should be ran. It's hard to say because without a runnable example or sample of code, I am just guessing at your intentions.

Although it sounds more like you are wanting some sort of callback system. When execution of `func1` is declared done, go to `func2`. There is nothing built into pyglet like this, you would have to have a clever use of scheduling. There are examples of this using pure python though. I personally use Twisted Deferred's for this.

Comment: My `event2` is not hard-blocking (and my `sleep` example is not appropriate). It's more like if we wera "out-of-game", while the others `events` are "in-game" events. My first column is in fact a "game-clock", and I would like my `event2` not to disturb this schedule, so for instance an instruction can be displayed for anytime, it is not considered as "game-time" so the game scheduler should be "paused" and "resumed" before and after that event. Hope this is clearer. I will think about a MWE, but not that simple. Thanks.